# Remove spaces , dots and special chars from a string and replace with hyphen in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string where there may be special characters, which I have to replace with hyphen

```
var str="123.This is,, :ravi"
```

The above string should be converted like this

```
var newstr="123-This-is-ravi";
```

I have been trying this

```
function remove(str){ str.replace(/\./g, "-"); }  //replaces only dots
function remove(str){ str.replace(/ /g, "-"); }   //replaces only spaces
```

Can any one help me doing this? I need to replace special chars with hyphen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You [should do the regular expression all at once](http://jsfiddle.net/EZVne/):

```
"123.This is,, :ravi".replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-")
```

Working example:

```js
$('p').html("123.This is,, :ravi".replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

That way it will not double up on hyphens.

One thing to note is that if the value ends with a period (dot), or even any whitespace, then it will end with a hyphen.

Answer (score 11):

You could also try to globally replace any non-alphanumeric character and white space by using the function

```
"123.This is,, :ravi".replace(/[\W_]/g, "-")
```

/[\W_]/g this globally eliminates any non alphanumeric characters and white spaces and can be replaced by anything you chose after the comma,

Comment: This should be the correct answer. not sure why people are lazy doing this over the console: 
    " @!#$DFASDFASD$#:,'\/ ssss".replace(/[\W_]/g, "-") results on: "-----DFASDFASD-------ssss"

Comment: Yes, covers my needs.